# Strange ng-model behavior inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build up a complex post request to run a report in my Angular app.

I have a list of inputs all dynamically generated via an `ng-repeat` a simple version of my html looks like this.

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in lists.filters">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]['type']/>
    <input type="text" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]['values']/>
</div>
```

`ng-repeat` is looping over this array

```
[
      {name: 'Advertisers',           value: 'advertisers'},
      {name: 'Sizes',                 value: 'sizes'},
      {name: 'Campaign IDs',          value: 'campaigns'},
      {name: 'Creative IDs',          value: 'creatives'},
      {name: 'Publishers',            value: 'publishers'},
      {name: 'Placement IDs',         value: 'placements'},
      {name: 'Seller Types',          value: 'seller_types'},
      {name: 'Impression Types',      value: 'impression_types'},
      {name: 'Bid Types',             value: 'bid_types'},
      {name: 'Seller Members',        value: 'seller_members'},
      {name: 'Buyer Members',         value: 'buyer_members'},
      {name: 'Insertion Order Ids',   value: 'insertion_orders'},
      {name: 'Countries',             value: 'countries'},
      {name: 'Site Ids',              value: 'sites'},
      {name: 'Sources',               value: 'sources'}
    ];
```

The JSON I'm sending back needs to be structured like this:

```
"filters": {
    "state": "all",
    "campaigns": {type:"include", values":[1,2]},
    "creatives": {type:"exclude","values":[1,2]},
    "publishers": {"values":[1,2]},
    "placements": {type:"exclude",values":[1,2]},
    "advertisers": {"values":[1,2]},
    "sizes": {"values":[1,2]},
    "countries": {"values":[1,2]},
    "insertion_orders": {"values":[1,2]},
    "sites": {"values":[1,2]},
    "bid_types": {"values":[1,2]},
    "seller_types": {"values":[1,2]},
    "impression_types": {"values":[1,2]},
    "seller_members": {"values":[1,2]},
    "buyer_members": {"values":[1,2]},
    "sources": {"values":[1,2]}
}
```

When I do this Angular throws an error: `'Cannot set property 'values' of undefined'` and `'Cannot set property 'type' of undefined'`

Yet if I do this (inside ng-repeat)

`<input type="text" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]/>`

Or this outside of ng-repeat

`<input type="text" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]['values']/>`

No errors are thrown and everything works fine. I'm positive that filter.value is defined and available on the scope even though Angular thinks it's not for some reason.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try my solution below ? Did it work for you ?

Comment: It sort of worked, but ended up causing other issues related to creating an empty object. Also from the Angular docs it says 'The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat' which seemed a little different in this case. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: OK. Thanks for taking a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular seems to think that `report.options.filters[filter.value]` is not defined.

You could initialize it. Either do it in controller or using `ngInit`:

```
<div ng-repeat="filter in lists.filters"
        ng-init="report.options.filters[filter.value]=
                 report.options.filters[filter.value]||{}">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]['type']" />
    <input type="text" ng-model="report.options.filters[filter.value]['values']" />
</div>
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/NWRZe/)**.

---

<sub>The above code assumes that `$scope.report.options.filters` is initialized.

If not, you should initialize it as well.</sub>